# "Cannot resolve table name" error when applying MySQL dump to RDS

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, amazon-rds, mysql-5.7

I'm setting up [replication of an external MySQL instance to RDS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.External.Repl.html).

Both the external MySQL instance and RDS run MySQL 5.7.10.

I've followed the procedure, but when dumping the database with `mysqldump` and sending it to `mysql` connected to RDS, I get the following error:

> ERROR 1215 (HY000) at line 2081: Cannot add foreign key constraint

`SHOW ENGINE InnoDB STATUS` on RDS shows:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2016-03-25 01:38:56 0x2ad07ddcf700 Error in foreign key constraint of table db/Prospect:
 FOREIGN KEY (`restaurantId`) REFERENCES `Restaurant` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Prospect_Zone` FOREIGN KEY (`zoneId`) REFERENCES `Zone` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18292 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci:
Cannot resolve table name close to:
 (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Prospect_Zone` FOREIGN KEY (`zoneId`) REFERENCES `Zone` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18292 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

OK, indeed the dump file recreates the tables alphabetically, so the `Prospect` table appears before `Restaurant` and `Zone`, which can explain the error.

But NO, because `mysqldump` adds `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0` to the top of the file, so it should work anyway.

So I decided to test it against a vanilla MySQL 5.7 installation, and no surprise, the dump is imported successfully with the exact same commands.

**What causes this error specifically on RDS, and how to avoid it?**

Comment: Please present the following: `SHOW CREATE TABLE Prospect\G`, `SHOW CREATE TABLE Restaurant\G`, and  `SHOW CREATE TABLE Zone\G`

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA My tables are large, so I trimmed down my dump file to give you a small, reproducible example, but this lead me to find out that this was a known bug (see my answer below). So, thank you for putting me on the right track, in some way :)

Comment: +1 for both question and answer. You found your own answer and you will eventually get back the 200 points. Moral of the Story for everybody else ? Read the Release Notes for MySQL (or any other RDBMS) before just installing.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA If I'm not mistaken, bounties are *never* refunded; but it doesn't matter, I've found the solution to my problem, this is the most important thing! Thanks for your comment anyway, I stumble upon your answers on this website regularly, and they do help a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just found out that this was a [bug that has been fixed](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=78955) in the next release, MySQL 5.7.11.

Extract from the changelog:

> InnoDB: Creating a table with a full-text index and a foreign key constraint failed when foreign_key_checks was disabled. (Bug #22094601, Bug #78955)

It took me time to figure out that the full-text index was the source of the problem, I had to trim down my dump file line by line until the dump could be successfully imported.

---

Unfortunately RDS does not support MySQL 5.7.11 yet, so I had to work around this issue. Here is what I did:

- created the dump file with `mysqldump` as usual
- opened the dump file and commented out all `FULLTEXT KEY` lines
- noted down these lines in notepad
- imported the dump to the replica as usual
- connected to the replica, and issued `ALTER TABLE` statements to add each full-text index I had in my notepad back to its table

This worked perfectly well and my tables are fully in sync now.